# For what purpose that window is on left side?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

Why that window is on the left side of screen-shot?

[image]

Comment: So you can run two APPS simultaneously. Open another app from your W8 start menu and drag it from top to left...

Comment: OIC. But only Win 8 apps run in that area. not other apps isnt it?

Answer (score 1):

As BigChris already wrote, this was the space of an Store App Which was displayed side by side to the desktop (Snap feature). In the middle of the screen you find a place where those 3 white dots are. Move the mouse to it, click it and resize the right Window to the left and the Desktop gets restored to the full size.